# Mirroring images in a blog article

Tags: image

When visiting [this website](http://de.francais-express.com/nachrichten/digital/-2498-phishing-ratgeber-so-erkennt-ihr-gefalschte-e-mails/), I spotted something weird about the images used. The sources of all images are mirrored horizontally and are being mirrored back with css: `transform: scaleX(-1);`.

Why would someone do that when posting a blog article etc. ? I can imagine that an image-search would not find the images on the given website, but security-wise I do not see any benefits. If anyone wants to steal one of the images, they can just mirror them on their own, which even works out with MS Paint.

Comment: Why do you think it is related to security?

Comment: What's even stranger is the amount of effort gone through to make this happen. Scroll down to the 'fire eye' logo and take the style off. The image in the response is already transformed to cater for the global style which is being applied. Nice spot. Still, not entirely relevant to security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two reasons, both only half related to security:

- The owner of the blog does not have the right to use the images, and does not want the owner of the images to find out that they are being used by image googling them. I assume Google will not pick up upside down matches. (There could also be other reasons not to want to have your images easily reverse googled.)
- The owner of the blog wants to prevent people from hotlinking the images. While not impossible, it makes it tricky to link to them (especially on e.g. a forum where you can not set CSS) if you only get them upside down. If nothing else, it is quite a fun prank...